# Magento Export order comment to a text file

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, sales-order

What will be the best practice to export Magento order comment to text file? Eg. What event I shall grab to get the data.

I'd like to grab the comment as someone add a comment. (then save it to a text file.  Saving to text file is not a problem.  )

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to do this using an observer you can try to listen to ** sales_order_save_after** and there just use:

```
$orderComments = $order->getAllStatusHistory();

$body = '';
foreach ($orderComments as $comment) {
    $body .= $comment->getData('comment') . PHP_EOL;

}
Mage::log($body, 1, 'some_log_file.log');
```

Notice that this will append all comments to $body before saving, so you will get repeated information on each save. You can tweak the code above if this is not what you need

Comment: $order->getAllStatusHistory(); Does not work ?? Any clue!!